# I want to Create my first URL using the command prompt

Tags: python, django

I have Django installed,but I was trying to create my first URL and I typed the following using the command prompt
"cd myproject" then again I typed "manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000" And I got the following output:

"System check identified no issues<0 silenced>
you have 17 unapplied migration. Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app: admin,auth,contenttypes,sessions."

Please what do I do to fix this problem so that my project can work properly?
Note that: I am new in using Python and Django

Comment: Follow the Django tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/). It will address your issue in details.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an advice to read the tutorial but in case you want to continue on your own (before next trouble), you need to run this in console in order to apply migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Read more about migrations and this command [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/).

Comment: Thanks so much. I have been able to do the migration.

Comment: @FredOriabor please accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to migrate the database first. But it's not error actually. It's just a warning. If you don't want to migrate(create DB tables) just ignore it. And you can still browse `127.0.0.1:8000`

**Migration command**

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Read Django documentation very carefully. [Django Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/)